# How to get an array of elements from jqLite object

Tags: angularjs, jqlite

I'm trying to write a test that checks that I have 3 elements, each with a different value. I have found them in my compiled component using `compiled.find('li')`, but I am unable to then map because I have a jQLite object instead of a simple array.

How do I get an array of the found elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Object.assign`:

```
var arr = Object.assign([],jqLiteObj);
```

Properties that parse as integers will be added to the array. Other properties will be added as named properties of the array object.

For more information, see

- [MDN JavaScript Reference - Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)